# Time complexity of Radix sort with dependent digit length

Tags: sorting, time-complexity, radix

In a problem an optimal sorting algorithm and its worst-case time complexity were to be found where there are n whole numbers with exactly (logn)<sup>3/2</sup> digits in base 2 each.
The solution is Radix sort with the time complexity O((logn)<sup>0.5</sup>n).
How is this possible?

I can't seem to get it just by using logarithm arithmetic